# Swift/MySQL/PHP 'Required Parameters Missing' Error

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, xcode

**Here is my swift for registering the user:**

```
//Information fields
@IBOutlet weak var user: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pass: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pass2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Message: UILabel!


//Register button
@IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {

    let Parameters = ["username": user.text, "password": pass.text, "email": email.text, "name": name.text]

    let url = URL(string: "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~lvweiss/prof4/register.php")!

    let session = URLSession.shared

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: Parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        Message.text = String(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print(json)
                }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.Message.text = String(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

**Here is the PHP:**

```
<?php
require_once 'DbOperation.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (!verifyRequiredParams(array('username', 'password', 'email', 'name'))) {
    //getting values
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    //creating db operation object
    $db = new DbOperation();

    //adding user to database
    $result = $db->createUser($username, $password, $email, $name);

    //making the response accordingly
    if ($result == USER_CREATED) {
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'User created successfully';
    } elseif ($result == USER_ALREADY_EXIST) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'User already exist';
    } elseif ($result == USER_NOT_CREATED) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Some error occurred';
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Required parameters are missing';
}
} else {
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'Invalid request';
}

//function to validate the required parameter in request
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields)
{

//Looping through all the parameters
foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
    //if any requred parameter is missing
    if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || strlen(trim($_POST[$field])) <= 0) {

        //returning true;
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**Here is the information I am trying to post to the database:**
iOS Registration Fields:

[image]

**And the error I am receiving from Xcode when hitting the register button:**

> 2017-11-14 00:42:01.529344-0500 WeissProf4[8754:662299] [MC] Lazy loading 
>       NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
>   2017-11-14 00:42:01.530670-0500 WeissProf4[8754:662299] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
>   2017-11-14 00:42:01.550941-0500 WeissProf4[8754:662299] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/leviweiss/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C98EE410-1CA2-4B4B-9ED8-A4F112C629E2/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2017-11-14 00:42:03.468653-0500 WeissProf4[8754:662299] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
>   2017-11-14 00:42:04.769899-0500 WeissProf4[8754:662505] [MC] Invalidating cache
>   2017-11-14 00:42:05.281372-0500 WeissProf4[8754:662299] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
>   ["message": Required parameters are missing, "error": 1]

I'm not sure what is going on, I know the PHP is successfully connecting to the DB and is able to post the required info (tested with Postman).  I am thinking it could be an error with how Swift deals with posting in PHP, although I am absolutely not a PHP expert.

Comment: If it works with Postman, then it's simply your Swift code that doesn't post the params correctly. Try adding a `var_dump($_POST)` to your PHP code and check what Swift actually posts.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you're posting a json string in the body instead of using a "normal" www-form (posting data like `param1=value1&param2=value2&...`). If you post a json string in the body, you need to extract the string and parse it manually in PHP. Check the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400639/post-data-to-a-php-method-from-swift

Comment: Thank you for point that out, works great!  Added an edit for the solution in Swift 4.

Comment: Add it as an answer instead. That way you can accept it, making others know the issue is resolved and easier for future visitors to find.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION Swift4:**

```
@IBAction func register(_ sender: Any) {

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~lvweiss/prof4/register.php")! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=\(user.text!)&password=\(pass.text!)&email=\(email.text!)&name=\(name.text!)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
}
task.resume()
```

}